# Can I sprout agents from the features of a GIS shapefile in NetLogo?

Tags: gis, geospatial, netlogo

I have a model which imports a landcover shapefile. I want certain types of the landcover to have turtles representing food `sprout` out of it.

If I try the following:

```
 set flats gis:find-one-feature landcover "CODE_12" "423" 

   ask flats [sprout-foods  1 
   [ set color black ]
   ]
```

I get the error: ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the org.myworldgis.netlogo.VectorFeature

Is there a workaround for this using sprout or do I need to do something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprout` is a patch command. Your flats variable is a vector-feature.

If you just want one turtle for that all features that match "CODE_12" = "423" could do something like:

```
let vf gis:find-features landcover "CODE_12" "423" 
foreach vf [
   let loc gis:location-of gis:centroid-of ? 
   crt 1 [setxy item 0 loc item 1 loc]
]
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks a lot. I'm still getting used to the GIS feature terminology. One last thing is can I all on multiple features from the shape file at once? e.g.  `let vf gis:find-features landcover "CODE_12" "423" and "424"`

Comment: check out gis:find-range and note that you can use wildcards "*". Though I'm not aware of any ability to do boolean searchers (eg, and, or, etc). You could always do two searches then concatenate the two returned lists.

Comment: For the sake of completeness and for anyone else working here I incorporated gis:find-range which worked for me. `let vf gis:find-range landcover "CODE_12" "411" "523"
foreach vf [
   let loc gis:location-of gis:centroid-of ? 
   create-foods n-foods [setxy item 0 loc item 1 loc
     set shape "circle"
     set size 0.3
     set color yellow
     ]
]`